# LINQ Exception: "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint", afraid of the relations!

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

I got the exception as soon I call the SubmitChanges()

The ids assigned are valid and already created in the database

the **"FirstLevelReprotDataSource"** is refers to **"ReportDataSource"** Class

All data come from same datacontext

[image]

```
GroupingDataMember gdm = new GroupingDataMember();
gdm.DataMemberID = 87;
gdm.FirstLevelDataSourceID = 61;
gdm.CreatedBy = "";
gdm.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
SelectedReportDataSource.FirstLevelReportDataSource.GroupingDataMembers.Add(gdm);
```

> The INSERT statement conflicted with
>   the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_GroupingField_ReportDataSource".
>   The conflict occurred in database
>   "HumanResourcesDocumentManagement",
>   table "dbo.ReportDataSource", column
>   'ID'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Any suggestions?

```
[Association(Name="ReportDataSource_GroupingDataMember", Storage="_FirstLevelReportDataSource", ThisKey="FirstLevelDataSourceID", OtherKey="ID", IsForeignKey=true)]
public ReportDataSource FirstLevelReportDataSource
{
    get
    {
        return this._FirstLevelReportDataSource.Entity;
    }
    set
    {
    ReportDataSource previousValue = this._FirstLevelReportDataSource.Entity;
    if (((previousValue != value) 
                || (this._FirstLevelReportDataSource.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
    {
        this.SendPropertyChanging();
        if ((previousValue != null))
        {
            this._FirstLevelReportDataSource.Entity = null;
            previousValue.GroupingDataMembers.Remove(this);
        }
        this._FirstLevelReportDataSource.Entity = value;
        if ((value != null))
        {
            value.GroupingDataMembers.Add(this);
            this._FirstLevelDataSourceID = value.ID;
        }
        else
        {
            this._FirstLevelDataSourceID = default(int);
        }
        this.SendPropertyChanged("FirstLevelReportDataSource");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain there's a record with `ID` 61 in the `ReportDataSource` table?  Can you also include in your question the create statement for the foreign key constraint the error references?

Comment: are you asking for foreign key creation from backend side, or DBML side? anyway i edited to include DBML version

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you are calling SelectedReportDataSource.FirstLevelReportDataSource.GroupingDataMembers.Add(gdm), you don't need to set gdm.FirstLevelDataSourceID = 61. The .Add takes care of setting the ID.

Secondly, try to avoid setting ID fields by value. It's better to stick with the Foreign Key by saying entity.ForeignKeyProperty = dataContext.ForeignKeyTableObjects.SingleOrDefault(o=>o.ID.Equals(50)); or whatever the ID is. That way you're binding an OBJECT to the entity, not an ID to the entity's field.

Thirdly, make sure that those IDs exist in the db- 87, 61, etc. And check to see if gdm.ReportDataSource is required. If it is, you're not setting it above. That could cause the failure.

Comment: @first: I set the id explicitly here as last hope to see where dose the problems came from, before this I started by setting the gdm.DataMember = datamemeberObj, and the same for the firstLevelDataSource, @second: i'll try it, @third: ids do exists (double check) since i got them form db in first place, and about the reportdatasource its assigned since i call the .Add() method.. i guess ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the ids explicitly in your example, why not add the object you are creating directly to the context's GroupingDataMember table and then submit changes to your database? In either case, take a look at the SQL generated by LINQ to get a better idea as to what is actually happening on the DB.

-m